# My Screen doesn't look HD

Tags: screen, gpu

I have installed lm-sensors to check my CPU temperature by using:
 `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` 
after that i print the code:
 `sudo sensors-detect` 
 it's gave me a lot of questions i answered it all by yes then my screen doesn't look HD any more not just in Linux OS but also in win10 
am newbie in Linux so if can some one help me i appreciate it .

Comment: What kinds of questions were you asked?

Comment: @NickWeinberg How to Make My screen display HD again .

Comment: You said `it's gave me a lot of questions i answered it all by yes` -- what were those questions you answered "yes" to?

Comment: @NickWeinberg
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
 Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively):

Comment: @NickWeinberg 
Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively):